# Launcher not opening completely

Tags: 14.04, launcher

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 when i installed Ubuntu launcher was working perfectly.But now it is not opening completely. when i keep auto hider off then it works perfectly.

[image: launcher:not opening completely!!]

Can any one help me with this problem ??

Comment: @the_Seppi it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fast and simple way to resolve this is to reset Unity to the default configuration:

```
rm ~/.compiz-1 ~/.config/compiz-1 -rf
```

NOTE: This will reset Unity completely, so you'll have to re-setup these settings.